# How to add a song to the iPod or iPhone if it was sync'ed with another computer?

Tags: iphone, itunes, mp3, music, ipod

I had a Vista machine and my iPhone was sync'ed to that machine.  But after I got a new machine with Windows 7, I moved that old computer away and is not using it.

So now I installed iTunes on this new Win 7 computer, and bought a new song from the iTune store, but I can't add this song to the iPhone.  It seems I have to erase all songs on the iPhone in order to add this one song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add music without syncing fairly easily:

- In the **Library** list in the left-hand column click on **Music**
- On the right hand side, go to the music you added to the iTunes Library that you want on your iPhone
- Drag the album or song onto your iPhone listing under **Devices** in the left-hand column
- Wait for the **iPod Sync is complete** message (even though you haven't used Sync)
- Click on **Eject iPod** and wait for the **do not disconnect** message
- Disconnect the cable and you're new song should be added

If you'd like to get the songs off your iPhone and put them on your new computer, [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/) can help you with that.

[image]

SharePod is freeware.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this article](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/copying-music-from-ipod-to-computer/) on iLounge. It details how you can retrieve music off of your iPod (Windows and Mac). I suggest doing that instead of just adding one song **onto** your iPod because eventually you're going to need to sync and it's better to just sync now.